# Moving a user profile to a different drive letter in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, user-profiles

Can someone please give me the right procedure to move a **USERPROFILE** from C drive to D drive in Windows XP?  I found two questions on this forum and in one question the link is dead:  [How do you move your profile folder in Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/5604/how-do-you-move-your-profile-folder-in-windows-xp)

And another one, [Move Windows profile directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/77214/move-windows-profile-directory), suggests using **mklink** which does not work in XP.  I tried dragging the user's profile with the right mouse button and selecting **Move Here**, but that did not work.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help here with some [hopefully] simple working steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this approach in a previous life, worked for me.

http://www.cpsb.org/system/dataprocessing/File%20and%20Settings%20Transfer%20Wizard%20instructions.pdf

s

Comment: it just creates a backup of files and folders. I want to move the USERPROFILE to another drive/location.

Comment: Can you not shift the folders to another drive? Let me have a looksy.

Comment: well for My Documents, i do this right click > properties > specify a path > click Move. But it does not move the userprofile.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [instructions here](https://superuser.com/questions/77214/move-windows-profile-directory) but instead of using `mklink`, since you are on XP, try [`fsutil`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_hardlink.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: when i try C:\>fsutil hardlink C:\docsBackUp "C:\My Documents". I get C:\docsBackUp is an invalid parameter.

Comment: @rashid: hardlinks can't cross volume mountpoints, you'll need to use junctions.  If XP has no native way of creating them via `fsutil`, use [`Junction`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) from Sysinternals.  For a clean install, using an unattended setup file is far easier.

Comment: its not a clean install, is it that hard to move a userprofile?

Comment: @rashid windows assumes your userprofile is on the drive your %windir% is on, so yea... it is that hard.